# Undefined class 'command_data' in object pattern - CLIPS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips

I'm using this Protege exported code on the first code block.

```
(defclass systemEntity
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot suspect
        (type SYMBOL)
        (allowed-values yes no)
        (default no)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete))

(defclass component
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role abstract))

(defclass sensor
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot theoretical
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot reading
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes internal-component)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass internal-component
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot short-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 0)
        (default 0)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot output
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot msb-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 15)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input2
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input1
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass adder
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass multiplier
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass circuit
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete)
    (multislot outputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot has-components
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot inputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
(create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass data
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot clock
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 1 ?VARIABLE)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot value
        (type INTEGER)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass reading_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write)))
        
(definstances facts 
    
    
    ([a1] of  adder
    
        (input1 [input_1])
        (input2 [input_1])
        (output
            [m1]
            [p1])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([a2] of  adder
    
        (input1 [p1])
        (input2 [p2])
        (output [out1])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([circuit_1] of  circuit
    
        (has-components
            [m1]
            [m2]
            [m3]
            [out1]
            [a1]
            [a2]
            [p1]
            [p2])
        (inputs
            [input_1]
            [input_2]
            [input_3]
            [input_4])
        (outputs [out1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([command_10_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 6))
    
    ([command_10_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 4))
    
    ([command_10_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_10_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 12))
    
    ([command_1_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 21))
    
    ([command_1_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 28))
    
    ([command_1_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 10))
    
    ([command_1_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_2_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 7))
    
    ([command_2_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_2_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 13))
    
    ([command_2_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 15))
    
    ([command_3_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_3_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 17))
    
    ([command_3_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 24))
    
    ([command_3_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_4_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([command_4_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_4_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 28))
    
    ([command_4_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 21))
    
    ([command_5_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 25))
    
    ([command_5_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([command_5_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 30))
    
    ([command_5_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 10))
    
    ([command_6_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([command_6_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 19))
    
    ([command_6_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 11))
    
    ([command_6_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 19))
    
    ([command_7_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 1))
    
    ([command_7_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_7_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 7))
    
    ([command_7_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 22))
    
    ([command_8_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([command_8_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_8_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 3))
    
    ([command_8_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 23))
    
    ([command_9_inp1] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_1])
        (value 31))
    
    ([command_9_inp2] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_2])
        (value 1))
    
    ([command_9_inp3] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_3])
        (value 6))
    
    ([command_9_inp4] of  command_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [input_4])
        (value 8))
    
    ([input_1] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_2] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_3] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([input_4] of  command
    
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m1] of  sensor
    
        (input [a1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m2] of  sensor
    
        (input [p1])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([m3] of  sensor
    
        (input [p2])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([out1] of  sensor
    
        (input [a2])
        (suspect no))
    
    ([p1] of  multiplier
    
        (input1 [input_2])
        (input2 [a1])
        (output
            [m2]
            [a2])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([p2] of  multiplier
    
        (input1 [input_3])
        (input2 [input_4])
        (output
            [m3]
            [a2])
        (short-out 0)
        (suspect no))
    
    ([reading_10_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_10_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m2])
        (value 31))
    
    ([reading_10_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_10_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 10)
        (object [out1])
        (value 28))
    
    ([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m1])
        (value 10))
    
    ([reading_1_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([reading_1_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [m3])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_1_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 1)
        (object [out1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([reading_2_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_2_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_2_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [m3])
        (value 3))
    
    ([reading_2_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 2)
        (object [out1])
        (value 3))
    
    ([reading_3_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m1])
        (value 22))
    
    ([reading_3_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m2])
        (value 6))
    
    ([reading_3_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [m3])
        (value 8))
    
    ([reading_3_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 3)
        (object [out1])
        (value 14))
    
    ([reading_4_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m1])
        (value 4))
    
    ([reading_4_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m2])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_4_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_4_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 4)
        (object [out1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_5_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m1])
        (value 18))
    
    ([reading_5_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m2])
        (value 16))
    
    ([reading_5_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [m3])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_5_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 5)
        (object [out1])
        (value 12))
    
    ([reading_6_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m1])
        (value 8))
    
    ([reading_6_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m2])
        (value 24))
    
    ([reading_6_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [m3])
        (value 17))
    
    ([reading_6_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 6)
        (object [out1])
        (value 9))
    
    ([reading_7_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m1])
        (value 2))
    
    ([reading_7_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_7_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [m3])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_7_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 7)
        (object [out1])
        (value 26))
    
    ([reading_8_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m2])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [m3])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_8_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 8)
        (object [out1])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_9_m1] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m1])
        (value 30))
    
    ([reading_9_m2] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m2])
        (value 30))
    
    ([reading_9_m3] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [m3])
        (value 0))
    
    ([reading_9_out] of  reading_data
    
        (clock 9)
        (object [out1])
        (value 30))


)
```

These are a function and a rule i wrote.
I want to get from the slot value of a command_data object the value and im getting the Undefined class 'command_data' in object pattern error.
I also attach a print screen from CLIPS's console.
Any help?
[image]

```
(deffunction calculate-adder (?r ?z)
    (bind ?g (+ ?z ?r))
    (bind ?f (* 2 2 2 2 2))
    (mod ?g ?f)
     )
 
(defrule initial-rule
?x <- (initial-fact)
(bind ?temp =1)
(object (is-a command_data)
    (clock ?temp)
    (object [input_1])
    (value ?l))
(object (is-a command_data)
    (clock ?temp)
    (object [input_2])
    (value ?z))
=>
(retract ?x)

(bind ?w (calculate-adder (?l ?z)))
)
```

Edit: I changed a few things and now i have new error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The allowed-classes attribute is very aggressive enforcing its restrictions. For example, you can place an instance name in the object slot if an instance exists so that its class can be determined:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defclass command
   (is-a USER))
CLIPS>     
(defclass command_data
   (is-a USER) 
   (slot object
      (allowed-classes command)))        
CLIPS> (make-instance [c1] of command)
[c1]
CLIPS> 
(defrule no-error
   (object 
      (is-a command_data)
      (object [c1]))
   =>)
CLIPS>
```

But if you use an instance name for an instance that has not yet been created and so its class cannot be determined, you'll get an error:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule triggers-static-error
   (object 
      (is-a command_data)
      (object [c2]))
   =>)

[CSTRNCHK1] A literal restriction value found in CE #1
does not match the allowed classes for slot object.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::triggers-static-error
   (object (is-a command_data)
           (object [c2]))
   =>)
CLIPS>
```

The simplest way to fix this is to disable static constraint checking:

```
CLIPS> (set-static-constraint-checking FALSE)
TRUE
CLIPS> 
(defrule no-longer-triggers-static-error
   (object 
      (is-a command_data)
      (object [c2]))
   =>)
CLIPS>
```

You can also remove the allowed-classes attribute from your classes or modify your rule so that the instance name constant is not referenced inside the slot pattern:

```
CLIPS> (set-static-constraint-checking TRUE)
FALSE
CLIPS> 
(defrule no-longer-triggers-static-error
   (object 
      (is-a command_data)
      (object ?o))
      (test (eq ?o [c2]))
   =>)
CLIPS>
```